# how to append a parameter and access it using @pathvariable in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to to delete a record by sending roll number to the controller.

student.jsp

```
<form:form id="deleteform" modelAttribute="deleteattribute" action="deleterecordstudent.html/${deleteattribute.rollNum}" method="post">
            <table>

                    <td>
                        <form:label path="rollNum">Enter Roll Number: </form:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="rollNum" name="rollNum" id="rollNum" />
                    </td>

                        <form:button id="delete" name="delete">Delete</form:button>

            </table>
```

RegistrationController.java

```
public class RegistrationController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/deleterecordstudent/{id}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String toDeleteStudentRecord(@PathVariable Integer id,ModelMap modelMap){
        System.out.println(id);
        return "deleterecordsuccesfulpage";
    }

}
```

Web.xml

```html
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

above mapping is not working, can any one help me on this ?
I want to pass roll num to url on pressing delete button and then fetching this value from path variable.

Comment: I have a few questions, 
where did you provide `modelAttribute="deleteattribute"` to the frontend? Can you also include the method you used to get this html page? And why do you have the .html in the `action="deleterecordstudent.html/...`? With the .html it is not the same as the value in your requestMapping. And finally, shouldn't you use `@PathVariable("id") ...`?

Comment: .html is a url pattern defined in web.xml. I just want to know that how i can create a url on delete button action so that it will hit my toDeleteStudentRecord method.

Comment: Include the error message you are getting in your question and try adding `@PathVariable("id") Integer id`

Comment: Of course it won't work, the form is being sent to `/deleterecordstudent.html` not `/deleterecordstudent` hence it won't match. Next to that your controller will never be matched as you mapped your servlet to `*.html` whereas you should have used `/` or `/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your web.xml url-pattern to the example below:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Since you included the .html, your request isn't directed to Spring's Dispatcher servlet.

You should also change your method to this. The value in your RequestMapping should match the url in your form action attribute exactly.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/deleterecordstudent.html/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String toDeleteStudentRecord(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, ModelMap modelMap){
        System.out.println(id);
        return "deleterecordsuccesfulpage";
    }
```